# error when using a bundle in an iOS project / how to create a correct bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I'm trying to include a static library in an iOS project. I imported the whole static library project then I linked the lib in the 'target dependencies' and 'link binary with libraries' as that's explained here: http://www.applausible.com/blog/?p=657

But then I'm getting this error when testing the app :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/alexis/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/9811107D-0D7E-4178-ACCE-BF43E3043770/PlazappPartnerTest.app> (loaded)' with name 'LauncherView''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x188a052 ......
```

I guess it can't access the .xib file but since it's included in my library I don't know why.
How do I make the main project 'see' the .xib file? (If that's actually the problem...)

EDIT:

I tried to make a bundle containing the .xib files and I included it to my main project but I can't use this bundle. I tried this :

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"BundleName" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];

NSError *error;
[bundle loadAndReturnError:&error];

NSLog(@"bundle error : %@", [error userInfo]);
```

And I got this error :

```
NSLocalizedDescription = "The bundle \U201cBundleName.bundle\U201d couldn\U2019t be loaded because its executable couldn\U2019t be located.";
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The bundle\U2019s executable couldn\U2019t be located.";
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "Try reinstalling the bundle.";
```

What's the problem?

I think I can't load a bundle containing non-executables resources like .xib files. Am I right?

But then, how can load my .xib from the bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frequently in Cocoa programming there's more than one way to get a bundle. I've had success with this:

```
NSBundle *libBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BundleName" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
```

Then load the nib with this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:libBundle];
```

This specific call you make to `loadAndReturnError:` loads the bundle's executable code. As this bundle probably doesn't have any executable code, just the collection of resources the library needs, it will give you this error.

**Edit** (Responding to a comment):

I made my bundle by adding a new target to my library project for the bundle. Starting with the Mac OS X bundle template, I added all my image, .xib, and other resources to the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase. I changed the base SDK to iOS (latest). Then I added the bundle to the library's dependencies and final app's "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase.

If you just try the add .xib files to a folder method, the .xibs are not compiled into nibs, and iOS can't read them.

Comment: OK so there's no need to load it. How did you create your bundle? I saw 2 methods but they don't work for me...

1. Create a folder Resources, copy the .xib inside, rename it in Resources.bundle and then add it to the project.

2. Add a new target in the project (Mac OS X > Framework and Library > Bundle) then copy the .xib into the bundle and compile it (with the correct architecture option).