# Bundle error in ios project

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle

Related to my precedent question 
[error when using a bundle in an iOS project / how to create a correct bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977784/error-when-including-a-static-library-in-an-ios-project)
I tried to create a bundle containing my .xib file and now my application doesn't run anymore.

I try to load my bundle like this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"BundleName.bundle"];
```

but it doesn't work:

```
NSLog(@"bundle : %@", bundle);
-> bundle : (null)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in the full path (i.e. starting from the device's root directory).